# Significantly lower download speeds than peers while torrenting

Tags: networking, download, bittorrent, speed, p2p

As you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef1r7.png) attached the average download speed I'm getting while downloading a torrent is 1 MB/s while my maximum limit from my ISP is 6.5 MB/s. One of the peers as you can see (last one in the Peer dl. column) has a download speed of 3.8 MB/s who is also still downloading just as me but I get lower download speed than them, there are also several others who have higher speed than me, some are getting even lower download speed than me. Why does this happen? Why can't everyone be at nearly the same download speeds while torrenting assuming they have the same ISP bandwidth limits.

*P.S. I asked the same question yesterday but a moderator felt that my question needed more detail hence closed my question, I have included the necessary details now for you to easily understand my problem.*

Comment: ISPs don't state their speeds in MB/s, they use mbps (roughly 8 times the value) Getting an actual download speed of 1MB/s on a 6.5mbps line is good (allowing for averaging, as it's actually more than you're paying for) Double-check your figures/units.

Comment: @Tetsujin I wrote 6.5MB/s on purpose because that's literally what I get, I have a broadband plan that has a speed limit of Mb/s (MegaBits).